# webRTC change device

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Using javascript how can the selected camera be changed in webRTC? By opening the webrtc device panel the camera/mic can be changed - then the page asks you to refresh.

Assuming there is no way to change the devices without refreshing, how can the webrtc device panel be opened through javascript?

Comment: You want to be able to choose the device FOR the user? Or provide a better way for them to make the choice? Do you want to do this Mid Stream(like swapping camera angles)?

Comment: Idealy, change mid stream. If that's not possible then providing a better user experience to change the camera (i.e. popping up the select device panel) would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox just implemented an early version of what's needed to switch streams (switch cameras) in mid-peerconnection-call, using the brand-new rtpSender (formerly referred to as "doohickey" in the standards committee.

rtpSender.replaceTrack(new_track, success, failure).  It assumes you already have a (separate) mediastream with the other camera open.  it's a bit extra tricky on Android since you can only have one camera active at a time.

Chrome tends to limit your device choices unless you use the device enumerator and specify a device.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked in firefox(desktop browser), in between webrtc call, i just called

```
navigator.getUserMedia({
        'audio': true, 
        'video': {...
```

it gives me the options to choose devices, I have only one camera, so only that option, but for mic, i get multiple options, also checked in chrome, since in chrome, you do not get an option to choose mic options, it just gives me the option of allow/deny.

Comment: Yep. getUserMedia will get a second instance of camera/mic rather than grabbing the original.

Comment: so, you do not want to end the current call and start new one with the new stream?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the getUserMedia API to request access to the camera and then pass in a MediaStreamConstraints object that specifies the desired camera.

Here's an example code snippet that selects the front-facing camera:

```
const constraints = {
  video: { 
    facingMode: { exact: "user" } 
  } 
};

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
  .then((stream) => {
    // do something with the stream
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```